# What is the functional equivalent of if (condition) then { apply function that returns same type } in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I've been experimenting with moderate doses of functional approach to some of my C# projects recently and I've had some success in simplifying and streamlining large portions of the code.

My question is:

**Is there an established, "functional" way of chaining *conditional* transformations (conditional applications of a Func<T,T>) on an object (of type T) in C#?**

Or alternatively:

**Is there a good reason not to do it this way?**

For example, let's say I have this brick somewhere and I want it to be more "functional":

```
public static string DoSomethingWith(string str)
{
    if (str.StartsWith("!"))
    {
        str = str.ToUpper();
    }
            
    if (str.EndsWith("#"))
    {
        str = str + str;
    }

    return str;
}
```

I could introduce very specific, non-reusable midsteps like this:

```
public static string DoSomethingWith(string str) 
    => str
    .GetAllCapsIfStartsWithExclamationMark()
    .GetRepeatedIfEndsWithHash();

public static string GetAllCapsIfStartsWithExclamationMark(this string str)
    => str.StartsWith("!") ? str.ToUpper() : str;

public static string GetRepeatedIfEndsWithHash(this string str)
    => str.EndsWith("#") ? str + str : str;
```

But this doesn't really improve anything in any meaningful way, does it?

However, if I introduce a generic extension like e.g.:

```
public static T IfApply<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> predicate, Func<T, T> func) 
   => predicate(obj) ? func(obj) : obj;
```

I can just go:

```
public static string DoSomethingWith(string str)
    => str
    .IfApply(x => x.StartsWith("!"), x => x.ToUpper())
    .IfApply(x => x.EndsWith("#"), x => x + x);
```

... at which point I would question the need for `DoSomethingWith` to exist at all, unless it's being reused, further reducing clutter in the code. It's clear, it's concise, it's easy to follow and pretty much documents itself (given an understanding of business requirements driving the transformations in the first place ofc). Obviously code (and logic behind it) is not always this simple, but it still looks pretty useful/convenient in many situations.

I was looking around for something like this, but my search fell flat. Why is that? Is it just a bad way to do things? Is it non-Csharpish? A heresy?

Thanks for any insight :)

Comment: I don't get your last question. What is whrong with that last code?

Comment: In his book Clean Code, Robert Martin makes the point that "names matter". If the method DoSomethingWith has a name that makes it readily clear what it is doing, anywhere you use the method the code will be easier to understand. On the low level, yes, you are changing a string to capital letters, where `.IfApply(x => x.StartsWith("!"), x => x.ToUpper())` would be good enough,  but maybe on a higher level the method is "transforming to normalized form" or "preparing for remote server request" and a name indicating that would help.

Comment: I agree, names matter. I strive to make my code self-document itself using meaningful names and all the other OOP principles. However, as you pointed out, if the code within the method is simple enough (and not reused), having one fewer method sometimes makes more sense than having a super-simple one-liner method with a slightly more meaningful name. For example, I see no benefit from using `str.GetRepeatedIfEndsWithHash()` over `str.IfApply(x => x.EndsWith("#"), x => x + x)`, even if I didn't have to waste space on defining the former.

Answer (score 1):

I like your `IfApply` method.

As to why this is not used more often in C#, let's directly compare your first and last example:

```
// first example (slightly condensed, but still valid C#)
public static string DoSomethingWith(string str)
{
    if (str.StartsWith("!")) str = str.ToUpper();
    if (str.EndsWith("#")) str = str + str;

    return str;
}

// final example
public static string DoSomethingWith(string str)
    => str
    .IfApply(x => x.StartsWith("!"), x => x.ToUpper())
    .IfApply(x => x.EndsWith("#"), x => x + x);
```

As you can see, you *can* write your first example in a similarly condensed way as your final example. Thus, there's usually *no need* for an `IfApply` method. Yes, writing single-line `if` statements might violate your current style guide, but style guides are a tool to create more readable code, not an end in itself.

Comment: Interesting. I think that your answer might be misled by the simplicity of my example, particularly in that the decision to apply sth is based on the parameter itself. In a more realistic scenario I find myself creating long compounds of LINQ queries with other variables in scope, somewhere in the middle of which I have to conditionally apply some transformation of the collection. So I end up defining a function like `.ConditionallyDoXYZ(condition)` which essentially boils down to a non-generic (= non-reusable = clutter) instance of `.IfApply(condition, DoXYZ)`.

Comment: Imagine sth like `if (col.Transform1().Transform2().Transform3().Count(Condition) > 3) { }`. Now Imagine I need to make the application of `.Transform2()` depend on `someBool`. Using a slightly simplified `IfApply` (with a `bool` param instead of `Func<T, bool>`), this could become `if (col.Transform1().IfApply(someBool, x => x.Transform2()).Transform3().Count(Condition) > 3) { }`. Still clear and concise. However, trying to resolve the condition with the standard procedural `if` forces you to introduce several extra lines of code incl. new single-use variables, am I right? Ugly imho.

Comment: @JacekKołodziejek: Indeed. Whether it is ugly or not might be a matter of taste - as Christopher mentioned in the question comments, well-named intermediate single-use variables or methods might actually *improve* readability, e.g. `if (Frobnicate(col).Count(Condition) > 3)` makes it clear that applying those transformations to col will frobnicate it. As I said, I do like your `IfApply` method, and I think the reason you did not find it anywhere else is because C# has an imperative history and this purely functional style is not (yet) idiomatic.

Comment: Agreed to everything you said here :) . I do wonder, however, why I really couldn't find it anywhere. I mean, the meme about rescuing princess with one LINQ query is at least 5 years old, I would think that doing some search online would yield me any results, even in the form a SO question whose answer points to some NuGet package containing some such methods, created several years ago and downloaded a few hundred times... makes me think I'm really doing something very wrong with this approach.

Comment: @JacekKołodziejek: I don't think you're doing anything wrong, just something untypical for C#. For example, `IfApply` is an extension method with an unconstrainted "this parameter", i.e., it will appear on *all* objects. Sure, it works, but it's something I tend to avoid in C#, even though I can't really explain why (probably because I don't feel comfortable "polluting" the "global namespace").

Comment: You don't have to "pollute the global namespace", at least not any more than LINQ does. If you need LINQ, you pull "using System.Linq;", otherwise you don't.